# How do you access an external USB hard drive and empty its Trash folder?

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, delete, trash

I am fairly new to Linux, Ubuntu, etc,
I am running lUbuntu 18.04.5.
Please note that I need to be given explicit instructions whenever I have to use Terminal (command line).

With my being so inexperienced and unfamiliar, I do not know how to empty the Trash folder on an external USB HDD (which I have been using for backing up my home folder).

I can see the Trash folder (which is called .Trash-1000) in the external USB HDD, using the GUI of the file manager for lUbuntu (which is called PCManFM). However, I do not see any way to empty the trash folder using PCManFM.

I am willing to use Terminal to empty the Trash folder, but I would need explicit instructions.

Comment: Have a look at https://lubuntu.me/pcmanfm-empty-trash-menu/   It tells you how to add the missing feature to *legacy* Lubuntu (such as Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

Comment: FYI:   Unless you're using a really old (i386 or 32-bit computer from 25+ years ago) I would suggest you used a modern Lubuntu; Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last *legacy* or LXDE release, and the only supported method of upgrade really is via re-install. You mention being "*fairly new*" so if the installation is "*fairly new*" I would consider it rather soon, as Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is nearing the end of it's three years of *full* support (2018-April + 3 years = 2021-April).

Comment: Hi guiverc. My machine is a Lenovo 3000 N100 laptop, circa 2006. it has a Genuine Intel(R) CPU  T2080 @ 1.73 GHz, 1 physical processor; 2 cores; 2 threads. When I installed lUbuntu 18.04 in 2019, as far as I could determine the next latest version at the time (which was version 20.04, I think) required a 64-bit machine and a faster  processor than my machine has. was i under a wrong impression?

Comment: Yeah you're out of luck, reading https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/29740/intel-pentium-processor-t2080-1m-cache-1-73-ghz-533-mhz-fsb.html implies to me it's i386 only   Lubuntu's last LXQt desktop for i386 was 19.04 (*alpha* only) so 18.04 LTS makes the most sense for you.

Answer (score 4):

> You can add this missing feature in LXDE, emptying the trash can using a menu thanks to the file manager actions, the easy way (it should be compatible with all versions of PCManFM except maybe Qt based builds, for now). Just open a LXTerminal and use these five commands:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli

mkdir --parents $HOME/.local/share/file-manager/actions

wget -O $HOME/.local/share/file-manager/actions/ask-trash-empty.desktop https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/lubuntu/trash-empty/ask-trash-empty.desktop

sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/ask-trash-empty https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/lubuntu/trash-empty/ask-trash-empty

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ask-trash-empty
```

[image]

> Now re-log in again, and that’s all.

This is just a copy/paste from https://lubuntu.me/pcmanfm-empty-trash-menu/, so all thanks should go to [RedWolf](https://lubuntu.me/author/redwolf/)

Note: A user at the Lubuntu site also mentions in comments  (which I can't test as I already have `zenity` installed)

> "You first need to install zenity (`sudo apt install zenity`)

Comment: Thank you, Norbert and guiverc.  Let me say first that as I recall i've always been able to empty the 'Rubbish Bin' that's on the Desktop in lUbuntu (via left click menu). My question here is not about that 'Rubbish Bin'. My question is about how I can empty the trash folder called .Trash-1000 in my external USB HDD. In any case, I performed the five Terminal commands, and then rebooted the machine (assuming that's what's meant by "re-log in again"). Unfortunately, there is still no obvious way to empty the trash folder for the external USB HDD.

Comment: I don't know how to install zenity - so I will look for a program called zenity in the Software facility on lUbuntu - tomorrow as its v. late here now.

Comment: I would use `sudo apt install zenity` ; but you'll find it more likely in `synaptic`  (the package manager, rather than Software store).

Comment: By now, following the above directions, I've done the command to install zenity. I'm guessing that zenity was installed all right. Next, I re-did the five Terminal commands recommended by Norbert. Then I re-booted the machine. I'm not seeing any obvious difference in the file manager (PCManFM), and I don't see how to empty the trash folder (.Trash-1000) in the USB HDD.

Comment: What *file-system* exists on your external drive?   I just had a test of it, and it worked. I mounted an external drive, copied files to a different directory on external drive, then moved (copies) to the trash, then went to trash and right-click had a "**Empty Trash Can**" option which cleared files (including on external drive). Note: external drives can be a little tricky, in that if you empty trash & drive isn't mounted .. they can't be erased.. you can always remove them manually at terminal (they'll be located in .Trash-1000/ (file in files/ and details in info/) but it worked for me.

Comment: It may matter where the right-click was clicked; after going to the trash (*my last comment*) I moved the mount-pointer to a white space in the area/pane where the 'trash' files were shown, so if I left-clicked there I'd be hitting white space; that's where I used right-click. I've turned the *bionic* (18.04) box off; this 2009 desktop runs Lubuntu *hirsute* (what will be 21.04 on release) so I can't see what it'll do in other areas of the window currently.

Comment: Regarding the file system on the external drive: After I sent the command sudo fdisk -l, the returned o/p says that /dev/sdb1 is of type Microsoft basic data. Additionally I created a new empty file in the external drive, using pcmanfm. Its permissions are that anyone can access, change or execute. By the way, what do you mean by, ".. you can always remove them manually at terminal (they'll be located in .Trash-1000/ (file in files/ and details in info/) .."? Also by the way, I don't understand what you wrote about right clicking at a location where right clicking would hit white space.

Comment: I'd use `blkid` to list details.. I assume it's NTFS. With the manually remove at terminal, I looked before I used the "Empty Trash Can" option and saw two files, one the jpg I deleted in .Trash1000/files/ and some metadata in Tash1000/info/ which could be manually removed (`rm`).  By white space, in the right pane of `pcmanfm` I had the files/directories that were in the trash, I moved the mouse-pointer between them in the *white space* so I wasn't clicking a single file/directory; but the action implied to them as a group.

Comment: Re the file system on the HDD: In the return from 'lsblk --fs' is "sdb                                                            
└─sdb1 ntfs   My Passport 4A38869438867EA7                     /media/paul/My Pa  sr0".  I haven't found an 'Empty Trash Can' option, including after right clicking in the white space in the right-hand pane of PCManFM between the contents (sub-folders) in the .Trash-1000 folder on the external HDD. Should I go through repeating the installation of zenity followed by the set of 5 Terminal commands?

Comment: Manually deleting trash can be covered in new question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308821/how-to-point-terminal-to-an-external-hard-drive-and-then-manually-delete-its-tr  @mikewhatever's answer I've used many times (it'll delete everything in trash on that drive, not specific items which is what I tried to cover two comments up)

Comment: Thank you, guiverc. The suggestion by mikewhatever has brought up another problem. (See my latest comment in the new question, in which I detail the problem that has arisen.)